# Questions about SQL query and transform row and col

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm a bit new to SQL and would like to do some query on these tables. the schema looks like this:

tb1:

| id | store_id | sold_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | store1 | 30 |
| def | store1 | 20 |
| ghi | store2 | 50 |

tb2:

| id | error_id | error_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jkl | error1 | error_type_A |
| mno | error2 | error_type_A |
| pqr | error3 | error_type_B |
| stu | error4 | error_type_B |
| vwx | error5 | error_type_B |

tb3:

| tb1_id | tb2_id |
| --- | --- |
| abc | jkl |
| abc | mno |
| def | pqr |
| ghi | stu |
| ghi | vwx |

I want to do a query and get a table like this:

| Stats | Error_Type_A | Error_Type_B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Raw_Count | 2 | 3 |
| Percentage | 0.4 | 0.6 |
| Error_Rate | 0.02 | 0.03 |

- Raw_Count: count of A/B error in total (tb2)
- Percentage: percent of type A/B error (tb2)
- Error_Rate: count of type A/B error (tb2) / sum of sold_count (tb1)

---

Now my thought is to do this in 2 steps, first to get a cte table like this, and then transform column and row.

| Error_Type | Raw_Count | Percentage | Error_Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Error_Type_A | 2 | 0.4 | 0.02 |
| Error_Type_B | 3 | 0.6 | 0.03 |

Here is the sql I wrote, but seems not working:

```
WITH cte (Error_Type, Raw_Count, Percentage, Error_Rate)
AS (
select error_type,
       count(error_type),
       (count(error_type) * 1.0 / (select count(*) From tb2)),
       (count(error_type) * 1.0 / (select sum(sold_count) from tb1)) 
from tb2
group by product_type
)
select Stats, [error_type_A], [error_type_B]
from
(
  select Error_Type, Percentage, Error_Rate
  from cte
  unpivot
  (
    value for States in (Raw_Count, Percentage, Error_Rate)
  ) unpiv
) src
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for Error_Type in ([error_type_A], [error_type_B])
) piv
```

Any idea on how I can solve this? Really need some help, thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
with
t as (
  select c.error_type, count(*) as cnt
  from tb1 a
  join tb3 b on b.tb1_id = a.id
  join tb2 c on c.id = b.tb2_id
  group by c.error_type
),
s as (
  select
    (select cnt from t where error_type = 'error_type_A') as a,
    (select cnt from t where error_type = 'error_type_B') as b,
    (select sum(cnt) from t) as total
)
select 'Raw_Count' as stats, a as error_type_a, b as error_type_b from s
union all
select 'Percentage', 1.0 * a / total, 1.0 * b / total from s
union all
select 'Error_Rate', 1.0 * a / (select sum(sold_count) from tb1), 
  1.0 * b / (select sum(sold_count) from tb1) from s
```

Result:

```
 stats       error_type_a            error_type_b           
 ----------- ----------------------- ---------------------- 
 Raw_Count   2                       3                      
 Percentage  0.40000000000000000000  0.60000000000000000000 
 Error_Rate  0.02000000000000000000  0.03000000000000000000
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/62E1ndVxquixWjvEd93z3v/0).